# [ROS2] Purpose of TextSubstitution

Tags: python, ros2, roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the ROS2 tutorials located at https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Tutorials/Launch-Files/Using-ROS2-Launch-For-Large-Projects.html#setting-parameters-in-the-launch-file, the 'default_value' within the 'DeclareLaunchArgument' directive is assigned to `TextSubstitution(text='0')` or similar.

My question is why that is necessary. Can't you just do `default_value='0'`? It seems to work without the TextSubstitution directive.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/390499/%5Bros2%5D-purpose-of-textsubstitution/) by [swiz23](https://answers.ros.org/users/52899/swiz23/) on ROS Answers with karma: 86 on 2021-11-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`TextSubstitution` is usually used to wrap literals in the launch description so they can be concatenated with other substitutions - but these substitutions must only be evaluated when the specific launch description is executed. In that context, it provides a uniform interface for all "substitutions".

https://github.com/ros2/launch/blob/b59bb6b88b40eaa82870542d93bdfb1a033d05c3/launch/doc/source/architecture.rst#substitutions

---

A partial purpose is that `TextSubstitution` must be constructed with a `Text` type, which indicates a value that contains a *unicode* string in a manner that is compatible with both Python 2 and Python 3 - so to work-around the differences in `string` handling/usage in Python2/3.

---

Originally posted by [aprotyas](https://answers.ros.org/users/74476/aprotyas/) with karma: 456 on 2021-11-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-11-10**:
So is the purpose then to work-around the differences in `string` handling / usage in Python 2 and Python 3?

**Comment by [aprotyas](https://answers.ros.org/users/74476/aprotyas/) on 2021-11-10**:
I'd say that's partly the reason - at least entirely the reason for there being the `Text` type.

More importantly, `TextSubstitution` is usually used to wrap literals in the launch description so they can be concatenated with other substitutions - but these substitutions must only be evaluated when the specific launch description is executed. In that context, it provides a uniform interface for all "substitutions".

https://github.com/ros2/launch/blob/b59bb6b88b40eaa82870542d93bdfb1a033d05c3/launch/doc/source/architecture.rst#substitutions

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-11-10**:
Seems like you should make this part of your answer proper, instead of a comment :)

The OP asks *why* `TextSubstitution` exists and what it's used for. Your comment seems to explain that.

**Comment by [aprotyas](https://answers.ros.org/users/74476/aprotyas/) on 2021-11-10**:
Yeah, I see how the actual "why" is in the comments. Edited to reflect that!

**Comment by [swiz23](https://answers.ros.org/users/52899/swiz23/) on 2021-11-10**:
So if you're not planning on concatenating the LaunchArgument with something else - but just passing it to parameters within a node, there would be no need to do TextSubstitution?

**Comment by [aprotyas](https://answers.ros.org/users/74476/aprotyas/) on 2021-11-11**:
@swiz23 I believe so, yes. Having said that, you never know how downstream launch descriptions will try to wrap around what you have - very contrived example, but still. As such, it's probably best practice to just use `Substitution` types for default values.